# Cannot find a differ supporting object 'myNums' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

im working with angular components and am having an error that ive simplified to the following. i have a NumList component.

NumList.ts

```
export class NumList implements OnInit{
@Input() options: number[];

constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){}
}
```

NumList.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let op of options">op</li>
</ul>
```

I also have a parent component:

Parent.ts

```
export class Parent implements OnInit{
myNums: number[]=[1,2,3];

constructor(){}

ngOnInit(){}
}
```

Parent.html

```
<app-num-list options="myNums"></app-num-list>
```

The following error is being thrown

> Cannot find a differ supporting object 'myNums' of type 'string'.
>   NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

it seems parent component is passing the name of the array myNums to NumList instead of the array itself. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [object binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) and use brackets around the attribute:

```html
<app-num-list [options]="myNums"></app-num-list>
```

This way you don't bind the string `"myNums"` but the actual value of the member variable.